# When will a process resume execution in user mode from kernel mode after a system call?

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls, context-switch

I used to think that a process may switch from user mode to kernel mode by system call, after the kernel routine is done, it will check if there is any other process which has higher priority before return to user mode, if not, it will return to user mode directly. But [Understanding the Linux Kernel, 3rd Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596005658.do) 1.6.1. The Process/Kernel Model just confused me:

> On a uniprocessor system, only one process is running at a time, and
>   it may run either in User or in Kernel Mode. If it runs in Kernel
>   Mode, the processor is executing some kernel routine. Figure 1-2
>   illustrates examples of transitions between User and Kernel Mode.
>   Process 1 in User Mode issues a system call, after which the process
>   switches to Kernel Mode, and the system call is serviced. Process 1
>   then resumes execution in User Mode until a timer interrupt occurs,
>   and the scheduler is activated in Kernel Mode. A process switch takes
>   place, and Process 2 starts its execution in User Mode until a
>   hardware device raises an interrupt. As a consequence of the
>   interrupt, Process 2 switches to Kernel Mode and services the
>   interrupt.
>   [image]

The following description just don't make sense

> Process 1 then resumes execution in User Mode until a timer interrupt
>   occurs, and the scheduler is activated in Kernel Mode.

I think that returning to user mode have noting to do with interrupt and what does it mean by "scheduler is activated in Kernel Mode"?

Answer (score 1):

The scheduler is the part of the kernel that performs task switching.  Each time the scheduler runs, it chooses which process should have control of the CPU next, and switches to it.  The scheduler needs to run often enough to ensure that all processes get a fair share of time on the CPU.

System calls can invoke the scheduler, but that alone isn't sufficient, because a process might spend a long time running code in user space, not making any system calls.  To ensure that the scheduler runs often enough, the kernel configures a hardware timer to periodically send interrupt signals to the CPU.  Each time the interrupt signal occurs, the CPU stops running the user program, switches to kernel mode, and runs an "interrupt handler" in the kernel that calls the scheduler.  Since it's triggered by a timer instead of by code, this works even if the user program isn't making any calls into the kernel.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but my question is when will a process resume execution in user mode from kernel mode after a system call. Would you mind explaining this description: **Process 1 then resumes execution in User Mode until a timer interrupt occurs, and the scheduler is activated in Kernel Mode.** I don't think this make any sense.

Comment: If the system call isn't one that runs the scheduler, or if the scheduler runs but decides to give the current process more time.  (Maybe there are no other processes that need the CPU at the moment.)

Comment: Don't you think that the word "unless" is better than "until" in the description?

Comment: I think my English is poor, I'm just fooled by the word "until" and "unless".

Comment: The timer interrupt is a separate event from the system call.  The system call finishes and returns control to the user program, and some time later, a timer interrupt returns the CPU to kernel mode for scheduling.  "Until" is the correct word for that.

Comment: Last question for the description **As a consequence of the interrupt, Process 2 switches to Kernel Mode and services the interrupt.**, I think it's not Process 2 that switches to Kernel Mode because the interrupt handler is not executed in the process context of Process 2 but the interrupt context, right?

Comment: An interrupt handler isn't a separate process.  It's part of the kernel, which is in every process's address space, so it runs in the context of whichever process was running on the CPU when the interrupt signal arrived.  Think of it as like a forced system call that the user program didn't ask for.

Comment: No, you are wrong, interrupt handler does not run in a process context, interrupt context has nothing to do with process, what you said may be true in an older kernel.But I'm not sure if interrupt handler run in a process context in 2.6.11 kernel version.